# Ubuntu asks permission for unrequired tasks [System Policy Issue]

Tags: permissions, password, policy

Out of nowhere, Ubuntu has been asking for my password/pin for every single thing I do.
If i want to **connect to wifi**, I am *forced* to put in my pin.
If i want to shutdown/restart, i have to put in my pin.

> I recently installed chrome remote desktop and heard that might be the
> source of this issue, but im not 100% sure on how to remove it and fix
> the password request issue

Wifi Pin request image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykxGt.png

Comment: I found an article which references to this same issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60283233/authentication-required-for-everything-i-do-in-ubuntu-19-10  There is a reference to files in /etc/polkit-1/localauthority.  I have a feeling this is where your issue is.

Comment: We have no OS & release details?  Are we to guess?  It reads like a user changed policy as well; what was done in the session prior to this *change* occurring was done? or packages installed?

Comment: Some security patches in Ubuntu 18 caused issues like this.  The solution is to upgrade to Ubuntu 20.  But not knowing what OS you are running, I cant give this as an answer.

Comment: @user10489 Ubuntu releases using the *year* format (eg. 18, 20) are different products to those using the *year.month* format (eg. 18.04 & 20.04).  The *year* products use the same identical user apps regardless of base OS (ie. release) which contrasts to the *deb* based 18.04/20.04 systems. Ubuntu has had *year* products like Ubuntu Core 18 since 2016, used to signify a *snap* only system.

Comment: If you want to be pedantic, what matters is the version of systemd.

Comment: solved! fix and @ to the person that fixed it is now in the question.

Comment: If you have solved your problem, please post an answer instead of editing the question.

Answer (score 0):

*The following was answered by the OP as an [edit](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1361449/2) to the question instead of posting an answer:*

The following content should be written in a file named say "nofurtherlogin.pkla" in /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/ by the command

```
sudo nano /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/nofurtherlogin.pkla
```

now paste the following contents in the file:

```
[Allow colord for all users]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-device;org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-profile;org.freedesktop.color-manager.delete-device;org.freedesktop.color-manager.delete-profile;org.freedesktop.color-manager.modify-device;org.freedesktop.color-manager.modify-profile
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=yes


[Allow Package Management all Users]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.packagekit.system-sources-refresh
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=yes

[Allow all users to shutdown]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.power-off-multiple-sessions
ResultAny=yes
ResultActive=yes

[Allow all users to reboot]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.reboot-multiple-sessions
ResultAny=yes
ResultActive=yes

[Allow all users to suspend]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.suspend-multiple-sessions
ResultAny=yes
ResultActive=yes

[Allow all users to ignore inhibit of shutdown]
Identity=unix-user:*
```

Restart after saved & exited.